# updating one way data binded values on change of location in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In form, there are set of labels and input fields populated from ng-repeat. I have used one way data binding for label (used `::`), so that user, while changing values, can see the old value (which is not possible if it was two way bind). Now on save, I am trying to re-load the same view(NB: one scenario, shows complete list) to see the saved data in db using `$location.path()`. But that is not updating the label. That is understandable, as location.path() does not actually reload/refreshes the page, until it is different view/route. I can not use `$route.reload()`, as it will always reload the same url. I could have another scenario, where user came to this view for one specific input and on save, I want user to be redirected to scenario one. So, `$location.path()` is the only choice, as per my understanding.
So, is there any way to update labels, while still using location.path?

**EDIT:**

I have view for route `editlookups/customertypes`.

scenario 1: You can visit this view and see the entire list of data in the form of `label---input field----delete button` populated by ng-repeat.

scenario 2: You can visit the same view for some specific value with route `editlookups/customertypes/Xdfg`.

In both cases you can edit the input and save and land on scenario 1 page to see the updated value. The reason for this is, one, to see the updated value and second, if you have selected specific value, deleted it and saved, you will like to go to entire list (scenario 1) page. So, a location.path() would work, if you were on scenario 2 first. However, it won't have any effect on one way bound label, if you were on scenario 1 first.

The reason, label is one way bound, because you could see the old value, till you saved the changes. Now after save, you want to see the new value and that is the issue. Any workaround would be appreciated.

PS: I wanted to post the picture, but this site policy forbids me.

Comment: what is the issue with `$route.reload()`?

Comment: I mentioned two scenario, in which user can see same view. One, the view shows complete list of saved data in form of label and input field to let user edit the values. Second scenario is, when user comes to the view for one specific value and hence sees only one, can edit and save as earlier. In both case, on save, I want user to be redirected to the same view with complete list scenario (scenario one), but with updated data this time.  1/2

Comment: Now, say, for scenario two, the url was `/sth/specificval` and after save, he is to be redirected to `/sth`, a `$route.reload` will not work, as it will load `/sth/specificval`. I have option of `$location.path("/sth")`, therefore. It will work correctly in case I came from scenario 2 to 1. However, it is not working, when I am already in scenario 1 and after editing saved the data, label does not update.  2/2

Comment: why can't you just reset the state of your data model and not have to reload? Question is hard to understand without any code or demo

Comment: Please see if the edit was clearer.

Comment: @charlietfl, I think one way bound label, once digested won't change again, till scope is re-instantiated and that won't happen for same url `$location.path()` change. A `$route.reload` would serve the purpose, but then if you were on scenario 2 first, you will not be able to come to scenario 1 after save. One more alternative is call `$location.path()` and `$route.reload()` in succession, but that messes up history.

Comment: best suggestion is create a demo in http://plnkr.co